# Can $\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{e^{c\sqrt t}-1}dt$ be evaluated in closed form?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Can the integral
>   $$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{e^{c\sqrt t}-1}dt$$
>   be evaluated in closed form using some known special functions? ($c \in \Bbb C$)

This is taken from a [question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157115/what-can-be-said-about-a-function-given-its-asymptotic-expansion), which aims a finding a function based on its asymptotic expansion. It appears to boil down to solving the above integral.

Comment: A simple approach, did you try for example wolfram online integrator? Pick for $c$ a value and see...

Comment: @imranfat I did try with $c=1$ and $c=2$ with no success.

Comment: did u try for 0 :P

Comment: Perhaps there is no closed form in terms of workable functions...I did a u-sub on that squareroot term, $\sqrt{t}=k$ hoping that integration by parts would give something, but no luck so far.

Comment: http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan%27s%20Notebooks%20IV.pdf
Maybe page 298 and following will be of some help

Answer (score 1):

Not a closed form, but it's quite straightforward to find a series representation of the integral.

Consider the case $\text{Re} (c)>0$, the opposite case can be dealt with in the same manner.

We simply expand the denominator as geometric series:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{e^{c \sqrt{t}}-1}dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-t-c(k+1) \sqrt{t}}dt$$

The integrals look quite familiar:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t-a \sqrt{t}}dt=2 \int_0^\infty u e^{-u^2-a u}du  $$

We consider a more simple integral:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2-a u}du=e^{a^2/4} \int_0^\infty e^{-\left(u+a/2 \right)^2}du= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{a^2/4} \text{erfc} \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)$$

Differentiating w.r.t. $a$ we obtain:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-t-a \sqrt{t}}dt=1- \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} a e^{a^2/4} \text{erfc} \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)$$

Finally we have a (slow converging) series for our original integral:

> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{e^{c \sqrt{t}}-1}dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(1- \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} c (k+1) e^{c^2(k+1)^2/4} \text{erfc} \left( \frac{c(k+1)}{2} \right) \right)$$